# Passing the an argument to Windows shortcut

Tags: vim, cygwin, shortcuts, mintty

I was successful in opening vim via shortcut in Windows.
It is simple as creating a target with

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/vim
```

Now when I open a file with this shortcut, it seems as though cygwin terminal (using bash) trying to execute the file, because after reading each line it outputs "command not found" This is unexpected behavior as the file is normal text file without shebang.
Also I have not been able to test this yet, but I would like to learn how to open the program with the directory set to the location of the file.

Comment: C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe "/bin/vim df"  <-- does that open file df? not sure what if df has a space.

Comment: In that case mintty.exe tries to execute "bin/vim df" as a program. I am currently able to drag a file to that shortcut and open it in vim. I need to find a way to pass in an argument through a target prompt in the short page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running mintty with `"-e"` switch?

*C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e /bin/vim*